# How to nest Select query with UNION?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How i can join user table in below query. I have username in my user table which i want to display along with below query results. i want to join with userid from user table so that i can fetch records from user table.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
select User_id ,login_date AS EventTime,'Login' AS ACTION
from Users_Login_Log(nolock)
where login_date > '2019-12-23 00:00:00.000'

UNION

select
 UserID, EventTimeStamp AS EventTime ,
 'Logout' AS ACTION
 from EventTrackLog(nolock) where  EventName = 'Default.Logout.Clicked' and EventTimeStamp > '2019-12-23 00:00:00.000'

) AS ES
ORDER BY User_id DESC, EventTime DESC
```

Comment: This query doesn't make sense. You will get rows from EventTrackLog for some user which most likely is not the same user. Why do you not use a join here? Or maybe those two things are isolated and you need to join this whole thing to your Users table? No idea. Sample data and desired output would help here considerably.

Comment: @SeanLange : can you suggest me how you will write Join query in above case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `join` on the derived table.  Also, you should use `union all` rather than `union`, so the query does not incur overhead for removing duplicates:

```
select u.user_name, es.*
from ((select User_id, login_date as EventTime, 'Login' AS action
       from Users_Login_Log
       where login_date > '2019-12-23'
      ) union all
      (select User_ID, EventTimeStamp AS EventTime, 'Logout' as action
       from EventTrackLog
       where EventName = 'Default.Logout.Clicked' and 
             EventTimeStamp > '2019-12-23'
      )
     ) es join
     users u
     on es.User_Id = u.User_Id
order by es.User_id desc, es.EventTime desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM
(
select User_id ,login_date AS EventTime,'Login' AS ACTION
from Users_Login_Log(nolock)
where login_date > '2019-12-23 00:00:00.000'

UNION

select
 UserID, EventTimeStamp AS EventTime ,
 'Logout' AS ACTION
 from EventTrackLog(nolock) where  EventName = 'Default.Logout.Clicked' and EventTimeStamp > '2019-12-23 00:00:00.000'

) AS ES
join userTable on es.user_id = userTable.user_id
ORDER BY User_id DESC, EventTime DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not to nest query for `UNION` but just join user table with both set of queries and order it using alias name as below:

```
SELECT ull.User_id AS UserID,
    ull.login_date AS EventTime,
    'Login' AS ACTION
FROM Users_Login_Log(nolock) ull
INNER JOIN usersTable ut ON ut.user_id = ull.user_id
WHERE login_date > '2019-12-23 00:00:00.000'
UNION
SELECT et.UserID, 
    et.EventTimeStamp AS EventTime ,
    'Logout' AS ACTION
FROM EventTrackLog(nolock) et
INNER JOIN usersTable ut ON ut.user_id = et.user_id
WHERE et.EventName = 'Default.Logout.Clicked' 
AND et.EventTimeStamp > '2019-12-23 00:00:00.000'
ORDER BY UserID DESC, EventTime DESC
```

Comment: But I see you have used UNION in this query

Comment: Yes, I used `UNION` in main query but retrieve and combine data set from two different tables. Above I said, we can just use `UNION` in the main query instead of using in the sub query.